# Find the derivatives of a smooth function between 2 manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $V$ be an m-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{k}$, let $p \in \mathbb{R}^k$, and let $M=p+V$. Similarly, let $W$ be an n-demensional vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{l}$, let $q \in \mathbb{R}^{l}$, and let $N=q+W$. Let $T:V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map. Define $\bar{T}:M \rightarrow N$ satisfying 
$$
\bar{T}(p+v)=q+T(v)
$$
That M and N are manifolds with $TM_x=V$ and $TN_x=W$  can easily be showed. Now we prove that

a) $\bar{T}$ is the smooth function on M in the sense that for each $x \in M$, there exists an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{k}$ containing $x$ and a function $F: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{l}$ such that $F \in C^{\infty}(U)$ and $F_{|U \cap M}=\bar{T}_{|U \cap M}$

b) Find the derivatives of $\bar{T}$ at $x \in M$. This means that we have to look for $dF_{x}(h), h \in TM_x=V$

I struggled to find the smooth extension $F$ of $\bar{T}$. With $x=p+l$ , I've set 
$$
F(a)=
\begin{cases}
q+T(a-p) \hspace{4mm},a \in B(x,\epsilon) \cap M=  p+V \cap B(l,\epsilon) \\
g(a) \hspace{20.8mm} ,a \in B(x,\epsilon) \cap M^c= p+V^{c} \cap B(l,\epsilon)
\end{cases} 
$$
and then tried to find an $\epsilon>0$ and appropriate $g:p+V^{c} \cap B(l,\epsilon) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{l}$ such that $F \in C^{\infty}(B(x,\epsilon))$, but I have no idea what to do next.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

For a) you could first extend your linear map $T:V\to W$ to a linear map $T^{e}:\mathbb R^k\to \mathbb R^l$ (which then will be smooth) and define  $F(a)=q+T^{e}(a-p)$.